# Hot to restore MySQL to specific previous date using dump file tacked today

Tags: mysql

I have MySQL dump today and for some reasons, I need to restore it to date 2 months ago how i can do that using MySQL command

Comment: You're going to need to get on the phone with Dr. Who. If you don't have their number, you're out of luck. The dump contains a snapshot of the current state. It does not contain a history of all the events leading up to that state.

Comment: @tadman so no solution even any way to delete all DB transaction to that dat

Comment: The dump doesn't have any transactions. It has the *result* of all the transactions. If stuff got deleted, it's not in there. If stuff got updated, the previous state is gone. This is why people take snapshots and periodically archive older versions.

Comment: I was going to make a joke about Apple TimeMachine, and then I realized that could be a solution. If one could rewind the state of the filesystem to two months ago, and restore the computer based on that date, perhaps one could then run crash recovery on the MySQL datadir and get the data as of that date (approximately). It comes with some risk, though, that the database would be unrecoverable from such a backup, because I doubt TimeMachine backups are atomic.

Comment: Another solution which could work is if you had binary logs of every transaction since an earlier backup, made prior to the date two months ago that you wish to recover. The technique is covered in https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/point-in-time-recovery-binlog.html But I suppose you don't have binary logs that far back, nor a backup from an earlier date.